# GCP : Serverless support for Relational Database

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on **Laravel** Framework 8.83.4 / PHP 7.4 application which currently uses **Eloquent ORM** for handling databases.
Currently, Eloquent ORM supports only Relational Databases. But, the Google Cloud platform doesn't support Serverless fully managed **Relational Database (RDB).**

Here are my findings so far.

1. **Cloud SQL and Cloud Spanner :** Supports RDB but not serverless.  A compute engine will be running 24/7. You have to pay even If you don't make any requests it.
2. **Firebase RealtimeDB, FireStore and BigQuery :** Supports serverless. But, it supports NoSQL only. But, Laravel inherently doesn't support NoSQL.
3. **Cloud Datastore:** Doesn't support either serverless or RDB.

Please correct me If I am wrong with my understanding above.
Please suggest any GCP or AWS or Azure solution which supports Serverless/pay-per-request Relational Database.

Thanks

Comment: I built a trick: https://medium.com/google-cloud/serverless-database-on-cloud-run-1a930eb00618

Comment: The closest that I know is Amazon Aurora Serverless. Due to the nature of Relational databases,  providing a truly serverless product is very hard to achieve and that means hard to make money providing such a service. A small standalone system will outperform a serverless product by a large margin. The primary reason is memory caches full of data from previous queries. There are companies trying various approaches, Google search for the latest news.